# Add objects to array javascript, and associative array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create array `filters_array`, first thing I noticed in console is that filter_group is nowhere to be found, is this a correct way to save objects?

Second, on second click I want array to grow, but at this point it is only overwritten, what am I doing wrong?

```
  //
  var filters_array;

  //Ajax call to filter movies, grab them and reload container
  $(".option-set a").on("click", function(){

    var filter_value = $(this).data("filter-value");
    var filter_group = $(this).parents("ul").data("filter-group");

    filters_array = {filter_group : filter_value};
    console.dir(filters_array);

    $.ajax({
      url: templatePath + "getmovies.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data){
        console.dir("ajax call success!");
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Did you mean `filters_array = {}; filters_array[filter_group] = filter_value;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Associative arrays" in JavaScript are simply objects. We usually call them "objects" or "maps", to avoid confusing them with "arrays" (which [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) in JavaScript, but let's ignore that for now).

You want to initialize your `filters_array` with a blank object:

```
var filters_array = {};
```

...and then within the click handler, to add an entry to it with the key being the value of the `filter_group` variable and the value being the value in the `filter_value` variable:

```
filters_array[filter_group] = filter_value;
```

So for instance, if `filter_group` had the value `"foo"` and `filter_value` had the value `"bar"`, you'd end up with a property on `filters_array` called `foo` with the value `"bar"`. You could then access that property in several ways:

```
console.log(filters_array["foo"]); // "bar"
console.log(filters_array.foo);    // "bar"
var x = "foo";
console.log(filters_array[x]);     // "bar"

// Loop through all of the filter groups you've added
var key;
for (key in filters_array) {
     // here, `key` will be `"foo"` (for instance)
    console.log(filters_array[key]); // One of these will be "bar"
}
```

Comment: In addition to TJ's answer if you want it to "grow" the object instead of over-writing it then you want to use $.extend(). the first parameter would be the object you want to extend & the second would the data you are extending it with.

Comment: @Precastic: There's no reason to use `extend` here.

Comment: @t-j-crowder You are right. I thought he wanted to extend the result of the ajax call with the data he already had. He just wants to extend the filter.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to create array filters_array, first thing I noticed in console is that filter_group is nowhere to be found, is this a correct way to save objects?

Yes, it is the right way, but it is right that you can't see it from the console, it is declared inside the function's scope. But you can do this if you need to access it from the outside:

```
var filters_array, filter_value, filter_group; //hoisted here

  //Ajax call to filter movies, grab them and reload container
  $(".option-set a").on("click", function(){

    filter_value = $(this).data("filter-value");
    filter_group = $(this).parents("ul").data("filter-group");

    filters_array = {filter_group : filter_value};
    console.dir(filters_array);

    $.ajax({
      url: templatePath + "getmovies.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data){
        console.dir("ajax call success!");
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
```

> Second, on second click I want array to grow, but at this point it is only overwritten, what am I doing wrong?

Well that's simple, you're initializing it again and again assigning it a new object every time, you have to do this:

```
filters_array[filter_group] = filter_value;
```

After having assigned to `filters_array` an empty object **outside** the function scope. Obviously you **need** to remove `filters_array = {filter_group : filter_value};` and replace it with that line!

Comment: This is totally wrong if you read what he is actually trying to do. filter_group should contain a string which he wants to use as the key for the key:value pair of filters_array = {filter_group : filter_value};

Comment: He wants to extend filters_array. The line filters_array = {filter_group : filter_value}; creates a new object every time. You include a comment about extending filters_array but make no mention of removing this line. Also moving the declaration of vars outside the function has no effect because you just over-write them each time, anyway.

Comment: That's not totally true. I'm telling him that hoisting the vars before the function is a way to access them outside the function itself(he said, in the question, that couldn't see them in the console; that is the solution, at least for the last of them). Regarding the filters_array you're right, my code works but I forgot to tell him to remove that line. Anyway, I thought it was implied.

Comment: I can see why you said that now but by "in the console" I think he is talking about the statement console.dir() which is in the scope of the function.

Comment: "first thing I noticed in console is that filter_group" <-- the `console.dir` function was used to print `filters_array`, not `filter_group`

Comment: Yes, but the confusion would have been because filter_array didn't contain a key with the contents of filter_group. Anyway, no harm no fuss. I didn't down vote you ;)

Comment: Uhm I understand your point. Well, we'll see, if @SandroDzneladze see the whole discussions :P anyway, downvote or not, when someone raises a question I'm used to answer trying to let my point of view understood :)

Comment: Your answer was pretty clear to me, thanks. But it seems the other one was much clearer and to my point. +1 for you and accept the other one.